# If $E$ is a subscheme of $X$, does $\textrm{Hom}(T,E)$ inject into $\textrm{Hom}(T,X)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme, and let $E$ be a subscheme of $X$ (a closed subscheme of an open subscheme of $X$).  If $T$ is a scheme, let $X(T) := \textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{Sch}}(T,X)$, and similarly for $E(T)$.

Suppose that $E$ is open, and let $i: E \rightarrow X$ be the inclusion morphism.  Then it is clear from the definition of the morphism of sheaves $i^{\#}: \mathcal O_X \rightarrow i_{\ast} \mathcal O_{X|E}$ that $E(T)$ injects into $X(T)$ for every scheme $T$ as $f \mapsto i \circ f$, because giving a morphism of schemes from $T$ to $U$ is the same as giving a morphism from $T$ to $X$ whose image is contained in $U$.

I'm less clear on the situation if $E$ is closed in $X$.  All we know is that there is some scheme structure $\mathcal O_E$ on $E$, and a morphism of schemes $(j,j^{\#}): E \rightarrow X$, such that $j$ is the inclusion map of $E$ into $X$, and $j^{\#}: \mathcal O_X \rightarrow j_{\ast}\mathcal O_E$ is a surjective morphism of sheaves of rings on $X$.

The morphism $j: E \rightarrow X$ still induces a function $E(T) \rightarrow X(T), f \mapsto j \circ f$ for each scheme $T$. *Is this map still injective?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your title question is yes and the *chic* way to state it is the category-theoretic statement

> Immersions of schemes are monomorphisms

proved as [Tag 01L1,  Lemma 25.23.7](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01L1) in The Stacks Project.